# R.java file is not getting created

Tags: android, r.java-file

I had R.java file in my android application. But I don't know, It is delete some how. To create it again I clean my project and also Rebuild my project by clicking on Build Project. I do not know what is the problem. It is not getting created again. Generally It gets created automatically whenever I build project.

Comment: May be , There are some error in xml or AndroidManifest. Please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some quick solutions to your problem might be,

- use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> command to "Organize Imports" and generate any missing import statements. Sometimes this would generate the incorrect import statement which would hide the `R.java` class that is automatically generated when you build.
- `R` is a generated class. If you are using the [Android Development Tools (ADT)](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html) it is generated whenever the project is built. You may have 'Build Automatically' turned off. Turn it on and build your project.
- Mistakes in your xml views could cause the R.java not to be generated. Go through your view files and make sure all the xml is right!
- Remove, if any `import android.R;`
- Restart your IDE.

Comment: Yeah I know it is automatically generated when we build. And my 'Build Automatically' is also turned on. I know about android.R import. It is not in my any activity class. I have checked my all imports. And I have restarted my IDE also. and I have check my layout xml files also. It is proper.

Comment: There might be something wrong with the xml's. check whether the names in the drawable or layout folder should not be in capital letters.

Comment: Thank you I have found the my mistake. By mistake I put 2 images with same name but extension was img.jpg and another img.bmp so after deleting img.bmp problem have been solved.

Answer (score 2):

If you are facing this problem after updating ADT, you should install that Android Build Tools . In my case installing Build Tools and restarting eclipse solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Delete any import to an `R.java` class
2. Move your cursor to a reference to any button/layout/string/whatever-coming-from-R, delete the last character, and hit `ctrl+space`. Eclipse will try to codehint you, automatically importing the correct `R.java`.
3. clean and rebuild.

Comment: I have checked everything. But there not codehint is getting generated and I did many times clean project and Build Project. But R.java is not getting created. Everywhere in R.layout.smting / R.id.btn1 etc.. showing Error under "R". And R.java file is missing.

Comment: So, Clearly there is a problem in your xml file.double check it once,

Answer (score 1):

You can create R.java file using aapt tool by executing following command.

```
ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/aapt
                    package
                    -v
                    -f
                    -m
                    -S DEV_HOME/res
                    -J DEV_HOME/src
                    -M DEV_HOME/AndroidManifest.xml
                    -I ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-7/android.jar
```

Generate Resource java code and packaged Resources

```
aapt  package -f -M ${manifest.file} -F ${packaged.resource.file} -I ${path.to.android-jar.library} -S ${android-resource-directory} [-m -J ${folder.to.output.the.R.java}]
```

You can find more detail about options on this link

http://www.herongyang.com/Android/Project-aapt-Android-Asset-Packaging-Tool.html

Answer (score 1):

yeah,maybe there are some error in your layou or drawable dir.
see the [problems tag] to get more detail

Comment: Thank you I have found the my mistake. By mistake I put 2 images with same name but extension was img.jpg and another img.bmp so after deleting img.bmp problem have been solved.