# "R cannot be resolved to a variable" just after creating android project?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Just after creating the new Android Application Project I get the error "R cannot be resolved to a variable" in my MainActivity.java file.

This is it's content:

```
package com.example.firstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Why am I getting this problem if the app was created by Eclipse choosing all the default options? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Did you try cleaning your project?

Comment: Start by double checking both copies of `activity_main.xml` and the manifest for any errors then Clean your project.

Comment: I just cleaned all projects and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Eclipse > Project > check Build Automatically > Restart Eclipse

Comment: I just fixed it. I deleted the project, created another one and then cleaned all projects. I have no idea why this happens though.

Comment: had you added "import android.R;" trying to do a quick-fix?

Comment: You solved your problem??

Comment: Remove import android.R it solves your problem

Comment: I tried cleaning the project and didn't do anything. Probably rebuilding and cleaning would have helped. But since I had not worked on the project yet I just created a new one (the error still appeared) and then cleaned all projects, then the error was gone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be because, there might be some problem in your res folder,

- The Main reason might be there could be wrong import file of `R.java`. So Remove, if any `import android.R;`
- There might be some images with same name, or some files with capital letters, or even there might be some errors in your xml files,
- Try rebuilding and cleaning your project.

For some quick solutions to this problem, have a look at this,

[R.java file not getting created](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14051970/1626878)

Comment: Nice explanation sahil... Very useful

Answer (score -1):

first try to clean your project and after that build it through eclipse.If the problem persists after this operation than it means its because of your activity_main.xml